# Is there a difference between a map and a morphism?

Tags: category-theory

There is a composition law for $X,Y,Z \in Ob(\mathcal{C})$,that's to say,there is a map $\circ$:
$$\circ :{\rm Hom_{\mathcal{C}}}(X,Y)\times {\rm Hom_{\mathcal{C}}}(Y,Z)\longrightarrow{\rm Hom_{\mathcal{C}}}(X,Z)$$
$$(f,g)\longmapsto f\circ g,$$
But we have not defined "a map" from an object to another yet.

Can we just rewrite it to ${\rm Hom({\rm Hom_{\mathcal{C}}}(X,Y)\times {\rm Hom_{\mathcal{C}}}(Y,Z),{\rm Hom_{\mathcal{C}}}(X,Z))}\neq \emptyset$ ?

Answer (score 3):

This composition law is part of the data. The point is not that it "exists" (of course it does, unless the target set is empty there are always functions to it), but that the definition of a category requires the choice of a specific composition function, which has to satisfy some properties.

Comment: I would add that the composition map does not need to be a morphism in the category, which seems to be implied by the OP.